# Trac wiki subpage linking

Tags: wiki, trac

I have Trac wiki page with multiple subpages like

```
(wiki:)Rootpage/More info/Details/Details on details
```

I need to create links on the last subpage on this path. If I put it

```
[[Rootpage/More info/Details/Details on details]]
```

Trac suggests me to create new page, even thought it regognizes the page with same/similar name. My typing is correct.

I get a red link when I add / in front of the link like

```
[[/Rootpage/More info/Details/Details on details]]
```

but when clicking it,it causes not found -error. Confusing. Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be hard to see whitespaces on page names.